# How do I open an SSH tunnel using ansible?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ansible, proxy

Most questions ask how to use ansible through a jumphost. That is not this question.

This question is: how do I open an ssh tunnel using Ansible?

I am trying to run the following command from ansible on a remote host so that the remote host opens an SSH tunnel to another server through a jumphost.

```
tasks:
  - name: Open SSH Tunnel
    ansible.builtin.shell: 
      cmd: 'ssh -L *:3376:localhost:3306 -fN -o "ProxyJump MyJumpHost" -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/{{ inventory_hostname }}/.ssh/myPem.pem myUser@remoteHost'
      executable: /bin/bash
    register: tunnel_result
```

This is a fairly complicated operation so my guess is that I don't have everything configured on the various servers as needed. Right now when I run this, the operation is timing out when trying to connect to "MyJumpHost".

Is anyone able to provide any advice on the necessary pieces to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Worse case, you can always resort to using the raw module with quote filters.

```
- raw: "ssh -L *:3376:localhost:3306 -fN -o "ProxyJump MyJumpHost" -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /home/{{ inventory_hostname }}/.ssh/myPem.pem myUser@remoteHost"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

This should work as though you are on the command line. However, remember to add SSH keys to the hosts to allow passwordless login. It can also cause timeouts. Learned the hard way when doing this for RSYNC between hosts that have no direct connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I moved on and just manually setup the tunnel with a bash script. But when I get back to it I will see if this works.